# how to submit rails form once with validation check if only all fields are valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have a form in my rails app but it submits multiple times when we click multiple times i want to submit the form once with checking all validations, I tried disabling the button on click but its only desables button with click, not actually send data nor checking validations.
please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ClientSideValidation](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations) gem to check if fields are valid (it uses model validation rules).
Your form will not be sent until all fields are valid.

Comment: but along with that I want to disable the submit button for restricting users to submit form multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using if or unless conditon

```
 <%unless object.new_record?%>

 <%=f.submit "save",:diabled=>'true'%>

 <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

ClientSideValidation gem has callbacks you can use to enable/disable submit button.
https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations#callbacks

```
// You will need to require 'jquery-ui' for this to work
window.ClientSideValidations.callbacks.form.fail = function(form, message, callback) {
  form.find('#submit-button').prop('disabled', true)
}

window.ClientSideValidations.callbacks.form.pass = function(element, callback) {
  form.find('#submit-button').prop('disabled', false)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a built in `disable_with` method which you can use on links and buttons. So you can do something like this: `button_tag "Checkout", data: { disable_with: "Please wait..." }`. Once your button is clicked once, the button will be disabled ( and no more data sent to your controller ) and the text on the button will be replaced with "Please wait ...".